# Firebase change location/directory of an existing record

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am experimenting with manipulating data in firebase and have run into the following question:

If i have 2 records inside of a subdirectory (A), and want to move them to subdirectory (B) how do i do this in javascript?

```
MainContainer
   - A
      - KEY 1 data
      - KEY 2 data
   - B
```

I am thinking copy the contents to a new record that saves to directory B and delete the directory A record, but does firebase provide an easier way to just move the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
So I came across this solution it will copy the code in your old directory and recreate it to the new directory..

moveFbRecord: function(oldRef, newRef){    
         oldRef.once('value', function(snap)  {
            newRef.set( snap.val(), function(error) {
                   if( !error ) {   }
                   else if( typeof(console) !== 'undefined' && console.error ) {  console.error(error); }
              });
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't provide a move operation.  You have to read the existing data, write it to the new location, then remove the data at the original location.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

You can update multiple nodes in a single operation. So after reading the initial data you want to manage you can set their fields to null to delete them and set the new ones to the target values